# No deviceToken and pushType after upgrading to Parse Android SDK 1.17.3

Tags: android, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

Since we've upgraded to Parse-SDK-Android 1.17.3 we are experiencing issues with the deviceToken and pushType of the installation objects. They both are undefined after the object's creation. We have also tried to downgrade the sdk to 1.17.0,  1.17.1 and  1.17.2 .  It seems that the new ParseFirebaseJobService's onStartJob method is not getting called. The documentation was strictly followed.

Manifest:

```
 <serviceandroid:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

build.gradle(app) :

```
implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3'
```

implementation 'com.parse:parse-fcm-android:1.17.3'

build.gradle(project):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
```

allprojects {
    repositories {
       ...
        google()
    }
 }

The Parse-Server's version is 2.8.2

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Me too!!! Our dev is trying to find a solution for a week now!! Did you find a solution?